# Follow site feature

Tags: my-site, site-settings

I have disabled the site feature 'Following content'  yet when I look at a person when searching for them I still see the follow option.  I have disable the site feature at the site level and at the mysite site.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate the **Site Feed** feature as well. Following content is just for the content part of the follow functionality.